# Error Loading Chart: this.library.charts.load is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization, chartkick

Hi I'm fairly new to the Vue Js Coding scheme and right now i am having a problem loading the geochart from chartkick

https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <!--Audience Gain Vs Loss-->
        <geo-chart adapter="google" :data="[['United States', 44], ['Germany', 23], ['Brazil', 22]]"></geo-chart>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
import BarChart from "@/components/Charts/BarChart";
import * as chartConfigs from '@/components/Charts/config';
import config from '@/config';
import Chart from 'chart.js';

import Vue from "vue";
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'

Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chartkick))
export default {
}
</script>>
```

I'm trying to show the geochart from the example but it seems i cannot use it. What am i doing wrong?

I've already tried using this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

and also this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  ...
</script>
```

and to finally i tried removing the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

But still the error is still appearing? Is there any workaround for this?

The Error message is : Error Loading Chart: this.library.charts.load is not a function

Thank you in advance

Comment: don't need `jsapi`, do need `loader.js` -- to load, use `google.charts.load` with package `'geochart'` instead of `'corechart'` -- with geocharts, you will need a `mapsApiKey` -- see `Chartkick.configure` in the [Google Charts](https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick#google-charts) section.

Comment: Sorry but i cant seem it find the mapsApiKey in the instruction. It only points me to put the loader.js to the page i ak working on